# Операции сравнения python

Tags: python

Не смог найти в гугле ответ. Вопрос, конструкции типа (х - целое число)

```
if x > 14: do something
```

и

```
if x >= 15: do something
```

будут иметь одинаковое время выполнения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А с чего бы ему быть разным?

```
In [3]: import dis

In [4]: dis.dis('if x > 14: pass')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (14)
              4 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]: dis.dis('if x >= 14: pass')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (14)
              4 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```